# Override a function without changing its other properties

Tags: javascript

When a function `a` is defined, Javascript stores in `a` the function definition but also other properties. Is there a way to override the function definition without changing its other properties?

For example, if I have this function:

```
let a = () => {
    return 'a';
}

a.myprop = 'my prop';
```

I would like to override it without changing the property `myprop`.

Comment: what do you like to *override*? the function `a` is a `const`.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why exactly do you need that, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I replaced `const` by `let` but it would change nothing to the question.
And it is not a XY problem. When a function is defined, Javascript stores the function definition along with other properties. I would like to change the function definition without changing the other properties. But my question might be unclear. However, I already have the answer.

Comment: "*When a function is defined, Javascript stores the function definition along with other properties*" this is fundamentally untrue - the function definition and the properties are not *separate* - each function is an object and each object can have properties. So, it makes no sense to change the function definition but not the properties - you are changing the entire *object* every time.

Comment: What seems to make more sense is if you have a composite object `obj = { func: /* some function */, props: /* some props */ }` - then you can change `obj.func` and leave the properties in place. This still makes me think it's an XY problem.

Comment: @VLAZ I have not said they are separate. I updated my question to make it clearer for people who will face the same problem. Is it clearer for you?

Comment: Again, I don't know *why* you'd want that. Makes very little sense to have a function with custom properties attach to it and change it with a different function keeping the previous properties. It has a design smell to it.

Comment: Yeaah! It has a design smell for sure. But it would may be possible to do it. I mean it is not a XY problem, this question could be asked. It is why I asked. Now, I know it is not possible. Just, @VLAZ, could you say me if the question now makes sense, this way it would help people wanting to do the same thing.

Comment: It'd be a very useful monkeypatching tool, but (un?)fortunately it's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, function *code* is immutable after the function's been defined. The only other thing to do would be to create a *new* function and copy all properties from the old function to the new one:

```js
// Examine results in browser console, not snippet console:

const a = () => {
    return 'a';
}

a.myprop = 'my prop';
console.dir(a);

const aNew = () => {
  console.log('aNew');
};
Object.assign(aNew, a);
console.dir(aNew);
```

Comment: Okay, thank you!! I accept it in 9 minutes when I can